# What do I do when my phone is pitch black due the the dumb brightness system going all the way to 0

Tags: lock-screens

This has happened to me several times and this time I cannot get in turned back up.

Comment: Can you elaborate your query?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The device you're using, Android version it is running. Also check and update the tags you've used to match your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tell whatever voice assistant you have (Google Assistant, Bixby) to set brightness to %50 or such. There's no way to set a minimum brightness.

Answer (score 0):

You can send this command via terminal, it will set brightness to near maximum (200 on 255)

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 200
```

Comment: Hello. Please follow [answer] to expand this post into a helpful one. Not everyone would be able to make sense of this post unless they are aware of both adb and settings command. Also, do tell us why 200?